# How do I handle error writing file in ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page which is supposed to transmit a file

All the code is surrounded in a try / catch Exception block

I use Response.TransmitFile to actually write the file, and when it fails (Due to permission issue in my case) the response to the client is some automatically generated html which details the error, with one part saying: "An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request."

Why does it say unhandled exception?

I caught the error because the headers were changed to text/html instead of the octet stream it would have been set to had the file proceeded successfully. But it seems like the call to TransmitFile writes its own content to the Response and then flushes it, which would really be undesirable!

What can I do?

```
try
{
    String targetFile = Request.Form["filePath"];
    if (targetFile == null) throw new Exception("No filename provided");
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(targetFile); 
    if (!file.Exists)
    {
        // file not found error
        throw new Exception("File not found");
    }

        Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; Filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(targetFile) + "\"");

        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // I write my own response in sb - I never see this content sent back!!
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of **file.FullName**?

Comment: It is a Windows UNC path to a file, i.e. \\server\folder\file.ext

Comment: Do you have any other code below the Response.TransmitFile? Also, why are you not clearing the response before you append header and transmitfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.TransmitFile writes the file directly to the Response stream without buffering it.

Since it has already been written to and sent to the client, you cannot take it back / clear headers, etc. in the catch block -- some of the response has already been sent to the client!

As an alternative you could use Response.WriteFile which will buffer the file to memory (provided your Response.Buffer property or Response.BufferOutput is set to true).  This should allow you to "take it back" in the case of an exception.

Keep in mind this can have performance implications for very large files, so choose the best approach for your scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.buffer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx

Comment: No worries. There is no substitute for testing, but I would guess that your approach below where you try and read the first byte of the file before transmitting it might outperform the WriteFile method.  I generally do prefer TransmitFile for larger files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get it working again. It seems like such a hack though... ugh!

```
using (FileStream stream = file.OpenRead())
{

byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

if (read <= 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Access denied");
}

Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; Filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(targetFile) + "\"");

Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);


}
```

It works now as I intend it to... if it does not read any bytes I assume it is an access denied error and go to my catch block and write what I want, not some pre-generated IIS html which ruins the process...

(I need to response with a jQuery postMessage response because this is an AJAX request)